How do you import key bindings into DBeaver
I am transferring to a new computer.
I can export key bindings from DBeaver Preferences → User Interface → Keys → Export CSV.
But I can't see anywhere to import them? What am I missing?

Instead of exporting the keybindings with the "Export CSV..." option in the Preferences window, you should use the general Export wizard.
Go to File > Export, open the "General" folder and select the "Preferences" option (it is important to select the "Preferences" option inside the "General" folder and not the "DBeaver" one). Now, in the list of preferences you can export, you will see an option for "Keys Preferences". This will output an .epf file.
Now, import this file through File > Import selecting the same option in the list and browsing for the file that you just obtained.
